# Super slow Ext4 directory traverse

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, filesystems, ext4

I'm currently working on a system that stores files in EXT4 partitions in large disk (10 TiB and 16 TiB ones). All disks are connected via SATA to an HBA (Dell PERC H310).

The file structure is like this: `/mnt/diskN/nXXX/store/some_id/twoletters/random_name` and the files varies in size, between a few KiB to some MiB.

As you can imagine, for a 500 GiB `/mnt/diskN/nXXX` folder we get a total of about 1.5 million files in there, which are in different subfolders. Each `/mnt/diskN/nXXX/store/some_id/twoletters/` folder can contain hundreds of small files.

My problem is that I am seeing very different performances doing directory traverses between disks that have the same specs on the paper, and even the same model in some cases.

To measure my performance, I'm doing a `du` on each `/mnt/diskN/`, seeing a 100x performance improvement between disks of about the same used space.

I have checked some things so far:

- Ext4 has `dir_index` enabled in all cases.
- All disks are mounted with `defaults,noatime`
- Executed `e2fsck -fyvD` on all disks to optimize directories.
- Ext4 reserved blocks are ~ 50 GiB of space to allow defragmentation.
- Non contiguous files are ~3.7%.

Example of a tune2fs output:

```
tune2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Filesystem volume name:   disk2
Last mounted on:          /app/storage
Filesystem UUID:          edc25fd5-48c9-48cc-86f9-115fe9fe1d2b
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index fast_commit filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg large_dir sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              305201152
Block count:              2441609203
Reserved block count:     13107200
Overhead clusters:        19533367
Free blocks:              1584334746
Free inodes:              294994216
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      883
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         4096
Inode blocks per group:   256
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sun Mar 27 16:55:23 2022
Last mount time:          Tue Jul 26 20:30:38 2022
Last write time:          Tue Jul 26 20:31:37 2022
Mount count:              2
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Jul 26 20:13:48 2022
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          9 TB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       17367446
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      c98a7272-eddd-4bd8-aac4-dfe714d4cc48
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0xfd641daa
```

The only difference I can see between the two disks is that one of them has ~9 TB written while other has only ~2 TB written according to `tune2fs -l` stats (however, current used space is the same).

Any idea how to improve the situation?
Is there any Ext4 feature I can deactivate to improve performance in this use case?

#### Update

I just found this information:

```
    14135350 inodes used (2.89%, out of 488308736)
      436787 non-contiguous files (0.1%)
       24565 non-contiguous directories (0.2%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 14119456/15886
   978816885 blocks used (25.06%, out of 3906469627)
           0 bad blocks
           1 large file

    14077331 regular files
       58010 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           0 fifos
           0 links
           0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
           0 sockets
```

~50% of actual existing directories are non-contiguous.
Could that be the reason of the slow performance?
How can I fix it?

Comment: You should not use `du` as a benchmarking tool, as it uses `stat()` to read the number of blocks a file uses, without reading the file itself. Additionally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749760/15087622) you can find a pretty detailed explanation about why `stat()` can be somewhat slow.

Comment: I used `du` because the real performance issue I'm seeing is reading the file metadata (not the file itself) during directory traverses. In fact, in my tests I'm testing that directory traverse in both disks (and making reboots to ensure the inode cache is not affecting this).

Comment: Is the directory structure, especially the depth, on the disks **exactly** the same?

Comment: Yes @mashuptwice, same number of “some_id” and “twoletters” folders (and even the same names in all disks, as those are pre-generated). Only varies the number of files per folder, but within the same magnitude in all cases (and distributed among folders in a similar way).

Comment: Did you already try switch the disks to different ports on the HBA? Does the performance stay with the disk or with the HBA port?

Comment: Already tried that, and no luck. The only factor I can see is that the filesystems that historically have had more number of files now are going slower, but I don’t know why. Specially after seeing low levels of defragmentation and with directories optimized.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer that I posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1733975/how-to-avoid-non-contiguous-directories/1734010#1734010).   As I wrote there, the problem is the combination of readdir() and stat() since on hard drives, each stat(2) of a file which is not in the inode cache will (in the worst case) result in random 4k read.  On hard drives, if you have thousands or millions of files, those random reads add up.    This is going to be true for most file systems.

Sorting the files so they are stat'ed in inode number order can help somewhat, but ultimately, the best way to optimize this kind of workload is to try to avoid the stat(2) system calls if at all possible.   If you are trying to store a lot of small blobs, it might be that a database with the appropriate indexes, might be a better choice for your application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root of the issue is the amount of folders and file fragmentation.

`e2fsck` returns ~0.1% of fragmentation (`files non-contiguous`) on the disk shown above, but that's the % over the total available inodes.

If I look at the perventage of files fragmented, it returns a 3.09%, with a 42.11% of folders fragmented.

On the worst case, I get 13.25% of files fragmented and 35.71% of folders.

I'm not sure about the root cause of directory fragmentation and how to avoid it, but I will post a separate question for that.