# How to avoid non contiguous directories

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, ext4

This question came from [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1733825/super-slow-ext4-directory-traverse).

I'm currently seeing some performance issues in my disks, and the stats shown between 16-43% of directories non-contiguous, and 0.42-13% files non-contiguous.

On the file part I think I have it: I have tuned my process to preallocate the complete file at once and then write on it, so the filesystem can allocate it correctly.

But for the folder fragmentation, I have no clue about why it happens and how to avoid it when creating and deleting files all the time.

Any idea?

What is affecting the directory traverse (and file `stat()`) more? file or directory fragmentation?

Is there any other filesystem which behave better for this use case? (lots/millions of small files in folders with a fixed depth)

Comment: You might want to look at the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-is-the-most-high-performance-linux-filesystem-for-storing-a-lot-of-small-fi). I generally recommend XFS for use cases involving large numbers of files but ReiserFS may be a better fit.

Comment: @doneal24 regardig XFS I have read a lot of different things, from poor performance with lots of small files, to the opposite. I'm not sure if it could a be a good pick as usually ext4 is recommended for this - except when it fragmentates the data a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't really with the folder fragmentation, I dare say.  The problem is that the stat(2) system call requires a seek to read the inode.   For a very large directory, the inode numbers tend to be all over the place, and if they aren't in cache, each 4k random seek for each inode is going to be painful.   So for example, compare the time to run these command:

```
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# time /bin/ls /path/to-really-large-directory > /dev/null
```

with:

```
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# time /bin/ls -s /path/to-really-large-directory > /dev/null
```

If you have your userspace program sort the files returned by readdir() in inode order, this can sometimes help.   One way of doing this using an ld preload to intercept the readdir() calls can be found [here](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/contrib/spd_readdir.c).   Also if it turns out that your program doesn't need to stat(2) file or you can find a way to avoid needing to stat(2) the file --- for example, if you have convenience alias so that 'ls' becomes 'ls -sF' so you get the file size and type displayed automatically, be aware that this comes at a cost.  If you are looking at a really large directory, or a large directory which is located on a remote server using either NFS or Ceph, it might be a good idea to forego that alias or get in the habit of using /bin/ls to avoid the alias when looking at this very large directories.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer and the explanation. I think you solution helps to deal with the symptoms but it is not the root of the issue. I have several disks, some of them added before to the system (more time handling files of this type). Those disks present a higher % of fragmentation and behave much slower than others with similar amount of files/folders.

Comment: Fox example, I have a couple of disks: one with 6.9 million files, 2.81% of them fragmented and 44% of directories fragmented. Other with 8 million files with 0.26% and 5.56% respectively. The last one performs much better even with a simple `du`. It may be that the second one's contents were copied mostly in a singkle day from another disk and they get ordered inodes on disk, but in my data it matches the performance of this metadata operations with the % of fragmentation.